# updating the state based on condition and adding new property finally retrieving the updated state

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

whenever the button is clicked i am passing the id , so my state is having three objects

```
state = items:[{
 id:1,
 material: 'iron'
},
 id:2,
 material: 'steel'
},
 id:3,
 material: 'coal'
}]


//reducer.js

case actionTypes.UpdateMaterialToShow:
  return {
   ...state,
   items: state.items.map(obj => {
    if(obj.id === action.payload.id){
      obj.['show'] = action.payload.status
    }
  }) 
}
```

so whenever the method is invoked i am passing the id and status, so i need to add the property to the state.items

expected output is if the clicked button is iron

```
state = items:[{
 id:1,
 material: 'iron',
 status: true
},
 id:2,
 material: 'steel'
},
 id:3,
 material: 'coal'
}]
```

how can i get back the updated state as shown above without mutating the state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) a new array is created. Whenever the object's `id` is equal to the payload's `id`, you need to create a new object based on the old one, with the updated properties.

You can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) or [object spread](https://redux.js.org/recipes/using-object-spread-operator) (like the example) to create the new object:

```
case actionTypes.UpdateMaterialToShow:
  return {
    ...state,
    items: state.items.map(obj => {
      if (obj.id === action.payload.id) {
        return { ...obj,
          status: action.payload.status
        };
      }

      return obj;
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Reactjs#spread-attributes`](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes).

```
return {
  ...state,
  items: state
    .items
    .map(obj => {
      if (obj.id === action.payload.id) {
        return {
          ...obj,
          status: action.payload.status
        }
      } else {
        return obj;
      }
    })
}
```